# Expulsion Card ruling in Mesopotamia

Tags: untagged

I don't have the English card text ready but the German one translates roughly like this:

> Move an opponents person or hut (with or without sacrifice token) up to 3 hexes from it's current location.

Can I move an opponents person which carries a sacrifice token with this card or can I only move the bare person?

Considering the parentheses I'd say that the part about sacrifice tokens moved along only applies to the huts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that text, I would rule that you could move *either* a person or a hut, and the ruling about sacrifice tokens applies to *both*.

If they had only intended the hut to have the sacrifice token clause, they should have written it as:

> Move an opponent's hut (with or without sacrifice token), or move a person, up to 3 hexes from its current location.

Comment: That's how we play it.

Comment: Alternatively you could argue that they'd have left the parentheses away if they wanted no distinction...